# phpstorm, subdomain handling

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide, subdomain, phpstorm

I have a project with some php and html files. URL for this project, for exmaple, - `mysite.com`

I need to create a subdomain for content, that will be moved to CDN: `assets.mysite.com`

Now, during development time, all files for subdomain are stored in a subfolder of my project `/home/user/phpstormprojects/mysite/assets`

In my html/php files I need to specify full path to my assets
`html://assets.mysite.com/mybest.png`

Of cource I want autocompletion and other features to work well.
So I need to set up phpstorm smth like `"assets.mysite.com" = "/home/user/phpstormprojects/mysite/assets"`

Could I do it?

Comment: I found one hack. Mark (/home/user/phpstormprojects/mysite/assets) as Resource folder. Define $cdn variable. Write path to all resources as (<?php echo $cdn; ?>/path_relative_to_assets_folder).  It's very ugly but it works. Looking for the better solution

Comment: There is no better solution unfortunately -- except making those URLs working already (in case if `assets.mysite.com` is not up and running yet) .. or just disable corresponding inspection in project settings (not the best idea as it may be useful in other cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using PhpStorm 7.1.3

1. Ensure your cursor has highlighted the project name.
2. At the menu on top select "File" then "New" then "Directory".
3. Name your directory. It will go under the project name (see step 1).
4. Right click on the new directory then select "Mark Directory As" a
   pop-up will appear giving you the option to mark the new directory
   as "Resource Root".

Put whatever directories you want inside it. PhpStorm will rename all references to them in your code.